# dynamic listbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm looking to add a checkbox that displays any "Not Found" items.
When this I would like to edit the Listitem

My code currently is working when I open userform2 and edit the Listbox without checking checkbox1.

However, when I checkbox1 is true, it correctly displays the only "Not Found" but when I go to edit the list item I receive run-time error 1004 method range of object _global fail

on:

```
Set rCell = Range(.RowSource).Resize(1).Offset(.ListIndex)
```

my full code: for userform2

```
Private Sub ListBox2_Click()
TextBox1.Enabled = True
TextBox1.Value = ListBox2.Value
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim rCell As Range
With ListBox2
Set rCell = Range(.RowSource).Resize(1).Offset(.ListIndex)
rCell.Value = TextBox1.Value
End With
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
OptimizedMode True
If userform2.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
Worksheets("Table").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Not Found", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
userform2.ListBox2.RowSource = vbNullString
userform2.ListBox2.ColumnHeads = False
Dim rng As Range
 Dim Cel1 As Range
 Dim LR As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = Sheets("Table")
 With ws
 LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 With userform2.ListBox2
 .ColumnCount = 1
 For Each Cel1 In rng
 .AddItem CStr(Cel1.Value)
 .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Cel1.Offset(0, 1).Value

 Next Cel1
 End With
 End With

End If
If CheckBox1.Value = False Then

With userform2.ListBox2
.RowSource = "Table!A2:A1048576"
End With
End If
OptimizedMode False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `CheckBox1_Click` event to control `ListBox2.RowSource`.  If `CheckBox1` is TRUE you clear RowSource and then add items to the list.

When RowSource is cleared `Range(.RowSource)` is the same as `Range("")` which of course errors.

Under these conditions, you'll need to devise another method to determine which row the ListBox refers to.

Comment: ahh makes sense.. Are you able to assist me further with getting this to work?

Comment: I probably could, if it were clear what you actually want to achieve.  Are you trying to set `rCell` to the cell related to the item selected in `ListBox2`? You'll need to track some information that links to ListBox index to the range index, which will be different since you load a filtered list into the ListBox.  FWIW, I think this answer answers the question asked.  Maybe ask another Q is you can't figure it out

Comment: Yes. So userform1.listbox opens up userform2 which only has listbox, textbox and check box. the userform2.listbox will display userform1.listbox and once you select the listboxitem, it can be edited with the userform2.textbox. 

and what I'm trying to achieve is when I check checkbox, it will display the new filtered data on userform2.listbox and I will be able to select the listboxitem and use textbox to edit